# can I add an incrementing value to query limit firebase admin sdk

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to increase my limit by ten each time this end point is hit, is there a way of doing this?? I was hoping to make it so I could possibly add an incrementing value say by 10 to the limit method.  I was thinking something like i+10 or something along those lines in order to   make the limit continue to increase, my route is as follows:

```
// get own user details
exports.getNextFive = (req, res) => {
  let userData = {}
  db.doc(`users/${req.user.uid}`)
    .get()
    .then((doc) => {
      if (doc.exists) {
        userData.user = doc.data()
        return db
          .collection("jobs")
          .where("userId", "==", req.user.uid)
          .orderBy("createdAt", "desc")
          .limit(10)
          .get()
      } else {
        return res.status(404).json({ errror: "User not found" })
      }
    })
    .then((data) => {
      userData.jobs = []
      data.forEach((doc) => {
        userData.jobs.push({
          userId: doc.data().userId,
          company: doc.data().company,
          position: doc.data().position,
          status: doc.data().status,
          link: doc.data().link,
          createdAt: doc.data().createdAt,
          jobId: doc.id,
        })
      })
      return res.json(userData)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err)
      return res.status(500).json({ error: err.code })
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where this code is run, but in most cases it'll be running in a stateless container, in which case you'll actually want to make sure that all values the code needs are pass in by the calling code.

For example, you can make the client/calling code pass in its current `limit` and then increment *that*:

```
.limit(req.params.limit + 10)
```

Comment: van Puffelen basically I am hitting the route as posted.  I would like the first ten items and then continue to add ten to the limit whenever the route is hit.  do I need to pass that req.params.limit in order to do that and if so how would I go about that